# Pass my indexPath from collectionView witht two different cells for the the indexPath

Tags: swift

I'm trying to pass my indexPath from collectionView in to my cell so that I could have two different cells for the the indexPath. I've tried passing instances of the controller and setting it to self in cell. I also tried protocol delegate and that didn't seem to work either. I use delegates quite often so I know I'm doing it right however, in this case my delegate function isn't even being called even tho I set the delegate to self in the Cell. I'm not sure what is happening but nothing seems to be working.

**CollectionView VC**

```
protocol ActivityAboutVCDelegtae: class {

    func passIndexPath(indexPath:Int)
}

class ActivityAboutVC: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    var delegate:ActivityAboutVCDelegtae?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.collectionView!.registerClass(ActivityAboutCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: CELL_ID)
        self.collectionView?.pagingEnabled = true
        self.collectionView?.alwaysBounceVertical = false
    }

    // MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource
    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return 2
    }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(CELL_ID, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ActivityAboutCell

        if delegate != nil {
            delegate?.passIndexPath(indexPath.row)
        }

        return cell
    }
```

**CollectionViewCell**

```
import UIKit

class ActivityAboutCell: BaseCell, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, ActivityAboutVCDelegtae {

    lazy var actVc:ActivityAboutVC = {
        let vc = ActivityAboutVC()
            vc.delegate = self
        return vc
    }()


    func passIndexPath(indexPath: Int) {
        print(indexPath)
    }

    override func setupView() {
        super.setupView()

        ActivityAboutSetup()
        backgroundColor = .whiteColor()
    }
```

Comment: `actVc` is **not** the controller in the storyboard. It's a completely different instance. You need the real reference to that controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) It is not clear what you want to achieve, but at lest the following solution will give you a way to call you `passIndexPath` method.
Replace

```
if delegate != nil {
    delegate?.passIndexPath(indexPath.row)
}
```

with

```
cell.passIndexPath(indexPath.row)
```

2) `UICollectionView` uses items, not rows. This is why the final result should be

```
cell.passIndexPath(indexPath.item)
```

3) `actVc` property looks unnecessary or even wrong.

Comment: I knew actVC was totally useless but I just wanted to try to set the delegate. What you showed worked. Thank you!!